Pre requisite before starting Solana Development
Hey everyone i have just entered the Development world and i would love to learn what all should i know before starting with Solana dev

Welcome 
If you are visual checkout Andy
HeyAndy on YouTube
If you like reading head to solanacookbook.com
The gist is you need to know JavaScript for front end - recommend React / NextJs for apps
For onchain / backend you need to learn Rust - most programs (smart contracts) are written in Rust.
